# EF Code-First to Existing Database Primary Key Error

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have applied Code First to an Existing Database.

I created an **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** and then chose **Code First from Database**.
(I followed this tutorial to be more specific : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx)

Here is one of my entities generated by EF:

```
namespace App.Data
{


    [Table("Bank")]
    public partial class Bank
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column("Bank", Order = 1)]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Bank1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It created the context and all classes correctly. But it gave this message for every table in the database. What should I do for this? Thanks.

> Warning   20  Error 6002: The table/view 'xx' does not have a primary key
>   defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a
>   read-only table/view.

Comment: "It created the context and all classes correctly." - What created the context and classes? Did you use a tool to generate your model? Post an example of one of your entities that is giving this error so we can help you.

Comment: So what is the actual primary key in the database?

Comment: it is **Id**, so I guess I have to remove **[Key]** from **Bank1**, right?

Comment: I'm not sure how the tool would have added [Key] to both fields unless it was a composite key in the database as well.

Comment: Yes, just remove the [Key] attribute. I don't know either how it got there. No tool is perfect, you probably get closer ;)

Comment: @GertArnold should I remove the [Key] attribute from foreign keys as well? thanks.